# How to install nodejs in a repository of my choice using apt-get in ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, terminal, apt-get

I understood that the command to install nodejs using the terminal and provided below

```
`sudo apt-get install nodejs`
```

will install nodejs in the root repository of my ubuntu. I am confused on how to install it to another custom location of my choice and will the common `cd` commands would do the job for me after changing the directory location to another place of my wish? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "the root repository of my ubuntu", but the command you mentioned installs node.js system-wide, so it will be available everywhere in your system. If you want to install node.js on another machine just repeat the command or use a node version manager to install and manage node.js.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion created I was just confused whether it will installed in the space where I have allocated  for the Ubuntu OS ( in SSD around 100GB for the root) or somewhere in my  home directory( which is in my HHD)  if I use the above method for installation.

Answer (score 1):

See here: [How can I change the apt-get install directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567863/how-can-i-change-the-apt-get-install-directory)

To do what it sounds like you want to do, download the tarball from [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org) and install that way.

I would highly recommend against doing that though.  There's nothing wrong with apt installing into the "root" and is standard practice.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I think this will help me : )